# Как избежать остановки приложения встроенным антивирусом?

Tags: windows-10

Всем привет, подскажите пожалуйста, почему самостоятельно написанная программа запущенная на чужом компьютере или загруженная в облако и потом скаченная от туда, блокируется антивирусом с сообщением "защитник виндовс предотвратил запуск неопознанного приложения"?

Вопрос: Что надо сделать что-бы программа будучи скаченной с облака или запущенной на чужом компьютере запускалась без такого сообщения?

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "защитник виндовс предотвратил запуск неопознанного приложения"

Вам необходимо подписать вашу программу доверенным сертификатом в одном из множества центров сертификации.
Подробнее по [ссылке](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/dashboard/get-a-code-signing-certificate)

Comment: Спасибо большое.